# Spring Task in Spring Cloud Dataflow on PCF can't find java

Tags: spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

i have a Spring Cloud Task fat jar that i have successfully deployed to SCDF running on PCF. i have created a definition for it and can therefore run it from the dashboard. fwiw it reads and writes from a database using Spring JDBC.

i'm trying to now set it up to run in a scheduled way and am having issues. i created a stream with a triggertask source and a task-launcher-local sink, and have configured the triggertask URI to point to the fat jar (via http, using a staticfile PCF pushed app).

the dashboard shows the two PCF apps (one for triggertask, one for task-local-launcher) both starting successfully, and it all runs, but the task fails every time with the error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/vcap/tmp/spring-cloud-dataflow-5903184636016162160/Task--582903409-1502669137014/Task--582903409"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

from what i can tell and surmise, the PCF app running the stream tries to fork and exec a java call, but since java is not in the path for PCF app containers i get the error

am i right? either way, how can i get the Spring Cloud Task (jar) to successfully run?

**Spring Cloud Data Flow: Server**
 1.2.3 (using built spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar)

**Spring Cloud Data Flow: Shell**
 1.2.3 (using downloaded spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar)

**Deployment Environment**
  PCF v1.11.6 (on Azure) 
  pcf dev v0.26.0 (on mac)

**App Starters**
http://bit-dot-ly/1-0-4-GA-stream-applications-rabbit-maven

**Logs**
[link to log](https://pastebin.com/zfjWc0VL)

Answer (score 0):

The stream definition is missing from the post. It is possible that you're using the `tasklauncher-local` sink, which is compatible *only* when using SCDF's local-server and it will fail with the attached error when running in CF. Please make sure you're using `tasklauncher-cloudfoundry` sink. This application was added in the latest release of app-starters.

As pointed in the previous SO thread, it is highly recommended that you use the latest release of app-starters *(1.0.4 is at least 10 months old)*. The latest releases can be found at the [project site](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/#stream-app-starters-and-spring-cloud-data-flow-).

Comment: i apologize. you did mention that before, and i blew right past it. and yes, i was using tasklauncher-local sink

Comment: that was indeed the issue, thanks! FWIW i am now seeing "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap", which is just weird

Comment: That's odd. Can you share the entire stacktrace? Also, please edit the post with stream definition. The more details, the better it is to answer what went wrong.